# bootstrap aside hide element of pagination on small devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

I have a web page with a DIV and a Aside, in the DIV I have a list with dynamic pagination, all works very well except in the small device Aside masked the pagination and I can not see the 2 page and 3 page.... of DIV

```
<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
....
</div>
<aside class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 aside-right">
....
</aside>
</div>
```

Comment: Can please create the working demo so we can show the issue?

Answer (score 0):

try to add the col-xs-12 to aside block:

```
<aside class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 aside-right">
```